# Problem with encoding with odbc in C# .net core on linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, encoding, odbc

I'm writing a C# program under linux and trying to use ODBC to connect to a database. The database is WIN1251 encoded, and I have question marks instead of characters.

OS: Ubuntu

Database: Interbase

Framework version: .net core 5.0

My attempts to solve the problem:

1. ODBC driver works fine, with the command from the console LANG=ru_RU. CP1251 luit isql-v DEVART_INTERBASE (run with WIN1251 encoding, connection parameters are exactly the same) I performed database accesses and all characters were displayed normally.
2. Replaced `string login = (string)reader ["LOGIN"]`  with

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[500];
var byteCount = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, buffer, 0, 500);
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
string login = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251").GetString(buffer, 0, (int)byteCount);
```

again, all characters were displayed normally. I could have used this method, but when I use INSERT or UPDATE command in the database, the non-english characters are incorrectly written, and I don't know how to solve this problem.

3. Similar code on windows works without problems.

I will be glad of any advice.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace net_core {
    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for InterBase};Server=10.0.2.2;Database=D:\\InterBase\\gdb\\DATABASE.GDB;Port=3050;User ID=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Client Library=/usr/local/lib/libgds.so;Charset=win1251;CharacterSet=win1251;Dialect=3");
            connection.Open();

            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText="SELECT LOGIN FROM USERS";
            OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            string login = (string)reader["LOGIN"];
            Console.WriteLine(login);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works correctly on Windows but not on Linux then it could be a bug...

Comment: How are you viewing the results.  Issue could just be the tool you are using to look at the results.  If you write in linux does can you read in window correctly from database?

Comment: I write result to the console. Also result is the same in debug view.

Comment: I think, odbc tool using wrong encoder to encode/decode text, but how I can set a correct one?